# uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is very simple Javascript code but I don't know why I am getting this error. I have checked the id names, put the script at the end of html body but nothing seems to work. Getting this error everytime at the nextBtn addEventListener.I saw a person doing the same on web but he is not getting this error.

```
// local reviews data
const reviews = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "susan smith",
    job: "web developer",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
    text:
      "I'm baby meggings twee health goth +1. Bicycle rights tumeric chartreuse before they sold out chambray pop-up. Shaman humblebrag pickled coloring book salvia hoodie, cold-pressed four dollar toast everyday carry",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "anna johnson",
    job: "web designer",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
    text:
      "Helvetica artisan kinfolk thundercats lumbersexual blue bottle. Disrupt glossier gastropub deep v vice franzen hell of brooklyn twee enamel pin fashion axe.photo booth jean shorts artisan narwhal.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "peter jones",
    job: "intern",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
    text:
      "Sriracha literally flexitarian irony, vape marfa unicorn. Glossier tattooed 8-bit, fixie waistcoat offal activated charcoal slow-carb marfa hell of pabst raclette post-ironic jianbing swag.",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "bill anderson",
    job: "the boss",
    img:
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg",
    text:
      "Edison bulb put a bird on it humblebrag, marfa pok pok heirloom fashion axe cray stumptown venmo actually seitan. VHS farm-to-table schlitz, edison bulb pop-up 3 wolf moon tote bag street art shabby chic. ",
  },
];

// select item
const img = document.getElementById("person-img");
const author= document.getElementById("author");
const job = document.getElementById("job");
const info = document.getElementById("info");

const prevBtn = document.querySelector("prev-btn"); 
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("next-btn");
const randomBtn = document.querySelector("random-btn");

// set starting item
let currentItem = 0;

// load initial item
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  showPerson(currentItem);

})

function showPerson(person){
  const item = reviews[person];
  img.src = item.img;
  author.textContent = item.name;
  job.textContent = item.job;
  info.textContent = item.text;
}

// show next person
nextBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  currentItem++;
  showPerson(currentItem);

});
```

Comment: these all need the correct selector: `document.querySelector("prev-btn"); ...` should be `document.querySelector(".prev-btn");` et all

Comment: My best guess is that the error is being thrown on `nextBtn.addEventListener()`. The reason I think this is because you're using `querySelector` to get the button, but you're indicating that `next-btn` is the name of a tag. I assume it is either an id or a class, so you will have to tell that to `querySelector()`. IDs are denoted by a `#` and classes are denoted by a `.`. If `next-btn` is an id, you should have `querySelector('#next-btn')`. If it's a class, you should have `querySelector('.next-btn')`.

Comment: Thanks that done the job